# How do I return a fixed size array of string literals from a function?

Tags: arrays, string, rust

This function will work for the type `i32`, but for the type `str`:

```
fn getValues() -> [str; 2] {
    [
        "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250",
        "46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538",
    ]
}
```

I get the error:

> ```
> error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
>  --> src/lib.rs:1:1
>   |
> 1 | / fn getValues() -> [str; 2] {
> 2 | |     [
> 3 | |         "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250",
> 4 | |         "46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538",
> 5 | |     ]
> 6 | | }
>   | |_^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
>   |
>   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `str`
>   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
>   = note: slice and array elements must have `Sized` type
> ```

This error makes me think I need to add the size but I did: a size of 2. What is Rust wanting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`str` is [the str primitive type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html), which is an [unsized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/unsized-types.html), having some limitations -- you encountered one of them.

To solve your issue, instead of returning a plain `str`, you need to return a `&str`, a borrowed string slice.  In this specific case you could even use `&'static str`, because string literals always have a `static` lifetime.

Also, because a primitive array is also a DST (dynamically sized type, another way to size unsized type), you need to specify the number of elements (which you did correctly).

So, the complete declaration would be `fn getValues()-> [&'static str; 100]`.

If you do not know the size of the array at compile time, you might want to use a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html), if you have some non-literal strings you likely want to use a [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html).  That would look like

```
fn getValues() -> Vec<String> { vec!["shoten".into()] }
```

P.S.: Do not shy away from those heap-allocated, owned types -- they do make programming easier.  Fighting with references and lifetimes is good style, but you don't need to do all that upfront, but instead optimize and refactor later.

Comment: Worked fine. I'm a little confused as to why I need to put static if string literals always have a static lifetime.

Comment: Lifetimes are part of the type, and types need to be completely specified for function signatures in rust. The is something called [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html) which simplifies _specific_ cases, but Rust only rarely used such deduced properties. In this case elision does not apply because there is no lifetime use for the input arguments (as there are none).

Comment: @camccar No the duplicate say an equivalent of this answer.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that says prepend with static.

Answer (score 2):

It's saying `str` doesn't have a fixed size, not that the array doesn't.  You can't *have* values of type `str`, you can only have them behind some kind of pointer.

Use `[&'static str; 100]`.

Comment: Curios, why can't I have values of type str?

Comment: @camccar it's because the str type doesn't have a size. Therefore, its size can't be calculated for pre-allocating memory on the stack. On the other hand, a reference does have a size (It's basically just a pointer)